# Access Request for LinkedIn API: Job Posters and Applicants with Use Case

Tags: linkedin-api

We are seeking permission to integrate the LinkedIn API into our platform, Eureka. This integration will streamline the creation of job contracts for individuals involved in candidate application processes. By utilizing the LinkedIn API, we aim to retrieve data from job posters and applicants, specifically when job posters log into their accounts and view candidates who have applied for the job. This will facilitate efficient contract generation. Our objective is to enhance the candidate application experience while ensuring accurate and secure contractual agreements between relevant parties.

I have carefully reviewed the Terms & Conditions of the LinkedIn API and would like to ensure that Eureka's use case complies with all stipulated terms and conditions.